# Resource file format processing in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a processor for a specific resource archive file format in Java. The format has a `Header` comprised of a three-`char` description, a dummy byte, plus a byte indicating the number of files.

Then each file has an entry consisting of a dummy byte, a twelve-`char` string describing the file name, a dummy byte, and an offset declared in a three-byte array.

What would be the proper class for reading this kind of structure? I have tried `RandomAccessFile` but it does not allow to read arrays of data, e.g. I can only read three `char`s by calling `readChar()` three times, etc.

Of course I can extend `RandomAccessFile` to do what I want but there's got to be a proper out-of-the-box class to do this kind of processing isn't it?

This is my reader for the header in C#:

```
protected override void ReadHeader()
{
    Header = new string(this.BinaryReader.ReadChars(3));
    byte dummy = this.BinaryReader.ReadByte();
    NFiles = this.BinaryReader.ReadByte();
}
```

Comment: When you say you have three char values etc., what encoding are they in? How many bytes do they take up?

Comment: regular char ASCII characters... 2 bytes I guess

Comment: ASCII characters usually take up one byte. `RandomAccessFile` reads two-bytes characters because it expects them to be UTF-16. You should check the documentation of your file. Guesswork ends up badly in such cases. What application wrote the file? Was it written in Java? Do you have the code?

Comment: You're right, it's 1 byte, my mistake. I used to read the file in c#, posting the code in my OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got lucky with your C# code, as it relies on the character encoding to be set somewhere else, and if it didn't match the number of bytes per character in the file, your code would probably have failed.

The safest way to do this in Java would be to strictly read bytes and do the conversion to characters yourself. If you need seek abilities, then indeed `RandomAccessFile` would be your easiest solution, but it should be pointed out that `InputStream` allows skipping, so if you don`t need actual random access, just to skip some of the files, you could certainly use it.

In either case, you should read the bytes from the file per the file specification, and then convert them to characters based on a known encoding. You should never trust a file that was not written by a Java program to contain any Java data types other than `byte`, and even if it was written by Java, it may well have been converted to raw bytes while writing.

So your code should be something along the lines of:

```
String header = "";
int nFiles = 0;

RandomAccessFile raFile = new RandomAccessFile( "filename", "r" );

byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
int numRead = raFile.read( buffer ); 
header = new String( buffer, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.name() );

int numSkipped = raFile.skipBytes(1);

nFiles = raFile.read(); // The byte is read as an integer between 0 and 255
```

Sanity checks (checking that actual 3 bytes were read, 1 byte was skipped and `nFiles` is not -1) and exception handling have been skipped for brevity.

It's more or less the same if you use `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [`MappedByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html). This will allow you to seek arbitrarily, but will also deal efficiently and transparently with large files that are too large to fit comfortably in RAM.

This is, to my mind, the best way of reading structured binary data like this from a file.

You can then build your own data structure on top of that, to handle the specific file format.